# How can I modify the joystick values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, joystick

I am creating a game, but I would need the left stick of the joystick to start from 0 in the down position (by default the center is 0, down negative and up positive), how could I do it? (I hope I have explained myself well, I feel my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to take your values in the data range [-1, 1] and normalize it to the [0, 1] range. The details of the formula can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range) but the basic formula is `(yAxis + 1) / 2` in your case for the Y-Axis values of your Joystick.